# Password field is empty when using wp_signon();

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-admin, login

I'm trying to make a custom login action for my custom login page. Registration page with custom user meta works fine, but the problem with login page is that everything should work, but it doesn't and only god knows why.

```
add_action('formcraft_before_save', 'login_user_addon', 10, 4);

function login_user_addon($filtered_content, $form_meta, $raw_content, $integrations)
{
    global $fc_final_response;

    foreach ($raw_content as $key => $value) {
        if ( $value['label'] == 'Adres e-mail klienta' )
        {
            $user_email_login = $value['value'];
        }
        if ( $value['label'] == 'Hasło klienta' )
        {
            $user_pass_login = $value['value'];
        }
}


  $user = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email_login );

  $creds = array(

    'user_login' => $user->user_login,
    'user_pass'  => $user_pass_login

  );

    $usr = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( !is_wp_error( $usr ) ) { 
            wp_set_current_user ( $usr->ID );
            wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $usr->ID );      
    } else {
        $fc_final_response['failed'] = $user_pass_login;
    }
}
```

The hook up there looks for the value from the form fields and it works okay because it returns the password from the $user_pass_login field. I made it for testing because I thought that the field does not send the password.

The problem is that when I'm typing in the correct password and the correct user name, it gives an error **password field is empty**.

It's driving me crazy because it's a last step to go while it comes to my project and I'm stuck with **possibly** simplest problem ever.

Best regards,
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked a while ago but I'd drop my answer which might help someone out there who is having same issue.

The reason why you got the **ERROR: The password field is empty.** is because the crediential array key for the password is incorrect. In your code you have the key as `user_pass` but it needs to be `user_password` as stated [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/).

This portion of your code

```
$creds = array(

    'user_login' => $user->user_login,
    'user_pass'  => $user_pass_login

 );
```

needs to be:

```
 $creds = array(

    'user_login'     => $user->user_login,
    'user_password'  => $user_pass_login

  );
```